# unwind doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

iOS 8.1

xCode 6.1.1

My storyboard is:
Tab Bar Controller -> Navigation Controller (NC) 1 -> ViewController(VC) 1 -> NC2 -> VC2 -> NC3 -> VC3

From VC2 to NC3 is Show details segue. I have a Cancel button in VC3 that is supposed to unwind to NC2/VC2.

I already add the unwind method to the header and swift files of Custom Class of both NC2 and VC2 and Ctrl+drag from Cancel button to VC3 exit.

I also tried Ctrl-drag to NC3 exit or NC2 exit

Nothing happen. Any thought? Workaround?

Already looked into [Unwind Segue in Xcode 6.1.1 with storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27295607/unwind-segue-in-xcode-6-1-1-with-storyboard) and [Unwind Segue not working in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654941/unwind-segue-not-working-in-ios-8/25842508#25842508) but don't see if I miss anything.

**EDIT**
Add println statement into the unwind method but nothing printed so the method is not call.
Header file code of VC2:

```
#ifndef SettingsViewController_h
#define SettingsViewController_h

#endif

@interface SettingsViewController (Workaround)
- (IBAction)unwindToSettings: (UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
@end
```

swift code portion of VC2

```
@objc(SettingsViewController) class SettingsViewController: UITableViewController{
  @IBAction func unwindToSettings(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){
        println("unwind")
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your unwind func code that's in VC2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a dummy project with the same structure: Tab Bar Controller followed by Navigation Controller and it doesn't work so I suspect it has something to do with Tab Bar Controller and the structure of the Controllers.

End up using Present Modally segue and

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

My unwind segues work just fine. Coming back from VC3, your code in VC2 should look something like this:

```
@IBAction func didFinishWithVC3(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) { 
    let controller = segue.sourceViewController as VC3 
    someVariableInVC2 = controller.someVariableInVC3 // If you need to get data from VC3 to VC2
}
```

Note that you need the `segue: UIStoryboardSegue` parameter.

Then just control-drag from your Cancel button in VC3 to the Exit icon above VC3 in your storyboard and select "didFinishWithVC3".

Comment: Yes, did all that but nothing happened :(